# Delete content from G-Drive Bin - Using Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I used **`.setTrash(true)`** method to move files in **bin**.This method(as a trigger) runs every other day.

But my **bin** size also **increases**.

I didn't found any specific solution that can delete files from bin **too**.

Comment: Use advanced drive service, see doc here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive